# Crons not reindexing the indexer after setting all

Tags: crontab, indexer, magento-cron

- I checked the crontab and it is showing me the correct entries. [link](http://i.prntscr.com/1_KAKaQqR2Wsaj3cdCHQ1w.png)
- I checked the cron_schedule table and it is creating and scheduling
  indexers. [link](http://i.prntscr.com/8FHumxa-RtSX680IVhS8Bw.png)
- I checked the bin/magento indexer:status and it is showing me the
  Ready status
- update.log output in magento/var/log is `WARNING: Update is already in progress.` [here](http://i.prntscr.com/ohFfGzmhSfijIIysU986SA.png)

But still when I login to magento admin System > Index Management, [here](http://i.prntscr.com/SXmsNoV1RIC6XLOZDY8WiA.png) is the status. Some indexers are showing last updated date one month ago. What's going wrong? Issue facing on ver Magento2.1.7

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your crontab am using this it's working fine,

```
* * * * * php -f /chroot/home/site/html/bin/magento cron:run  &> /dev/null
* * * * * php -f /chroot/home/site/html/update/cron.php &> /dev/null
* * * * * php -f /chroot/home/site/html/bin/magento setup:cron:run &> /dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks, all this already set in my crontab as well. http://i.prntscr.com/1_KAKaQqR2Wsaj3cdCHQ1w.png

Comment: Create any test file in your root and delete it otherwise write some mail function in that file and set the cron for that file. We need to the debug issue whether it's from server or Magento side.

Comment: Yes I checked it earlier, the issue is with magento. On server crons were working.

Comment: Try this command, php bin/magento magento cron:run